# Using template routes to create pages which have no channels in the URL

Tags: template-routes

I'm setting up landing pages for our adword campaigns and have created a channel called "adword_landing_pages". Right now the URL's for these are similar to:

www.prestwicklimited.com/adword_landing_pages/example_entry/

I want to have these display as:

www.pretwicklimited.com/example_entry/

I've activated the template route manager and added "/{adword:alpha_dash)" to the adword_landing_pages route_manager_route and set the route_manager_required to Yes.

When I check my site, every page now displays the adword landing page template. If I add a different path like "/adword/{adword:alpha_dash)", everything works as expected. The problem is, I want to get rid of the portion of the URL before the entry name.

Obviously I'm missing a step in this process or am completely overlooking an easier way to accomplish the task of creating landing pages that don't have the channel name in the url.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use the pages module instead of template routes?

Comment: Simply put Phil, I didn't know that was what the page module did. Thank you!